# ProtoBuf corrupts byte array during deserialization (extra 0's added)

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm using ProtoBuf.NET to serialize/deserialize some classes. I'm finding that on deserializing, I'm getting a corrupt byte[] (extra 0's). Before you ask, yes, I need the ***WithLengthPrefix()** versions of the ProtoBuf API since the ProtoBuf portion is at the starts of a custom stream :)

Anyway, I see

```
Original object is (JSON depiction):
{"ByteArray":"M+B6q+PXNuF8P5hl","ByteArray2":"DmErxVQ2y87IypSRcfxcWA==","K":2,"V
":1.0}

Protobuf: Raw Hex (42 bytes):
29-2A-20-0A-0C-33-E0-7A-AB-E3-D7-36-E1-7C-3F-98-65-12-10-0E-61-2B-C5-54-36-CB-CE
-C8-CA-94-91-71-FC-5C-58-08-02-15-00-00-80-3F

Regenerated object is (JSON depiction):
{"ByteArray":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAM+B6q+PXNuF8P5hl","ByteArray2":"DmErxVQ2y87IypSRcf
xcWA==","K":2,"V":1.0}
```

The extra `AAA*A` in the `ByteArray` member are basically hex 0x00's in base64.

The app logic is similar to

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var parent = new Parent();
    parent.Init();

    Console.WriteLine("\nOriginal object is (JSON depiction):");
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent));

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, parent, PrefixStyle.Base128);
        byte[] bytes2 = ms.ToArray();
        var hex2 = BitConverter.ToString(bytes2);
        Console.WriteLine("\nProtobuf: Hex ({0} bytes):\n{1}", bytes2.Length, hex2);

        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var backFirst = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Parent>(ms,PrefixStyle.Base128);

        Console.WriteLine("\nRegenerated object is (JSON depiction):");
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(backFirst));
    }
}
```

The DTO classes are

```
[DataContract]
[ProtoContract]
internal class Parent : Child
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ByteArray", Order = 10)]
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public byte[] ByteArray { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ByteArray2", Order = 30, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public byte[] ByteArray2 { get; set; }

    public Parent()
    {
        ByteArray = new byte[12];
    }

    internal void Init(bool bindRow = false)
    {
        base.Init();
        var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        rng.GetBytes(ByteArray);

        ByteArray2 = new byte[16];
        rng.GetBytes(ByteArray2);
    }
}

[DataContract]
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(5, typeof(Parent))]
public class Child
{
    [DataMember(Name = "K", Order = 100)]
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Int32 K { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "V", Order = 110)]
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public float V { get; set; }

    internal void Init()
    {
        K = 2;
        V = 1.0f;
    }
}
```

I do see that when I move `ByteArray = new byte[12]` out form the `Parent` constructor into it's `Init()` method, ProtoBuf works fine. However we have app logic that prevents that in the real version (vs the SO trim down code you see above).

Are we doing something wrong or is this a bug in ProtoBuf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we go:

```
public Parent()
{
    ByteArray = new byte[12];
}
```

Note: protobuf is designed (by google) to be both appendable and mergeable. Where append / merge is synonymous (for lists / arrays etc) with "append".

Two options (both possible via attributes):

- disable the constructor: `[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]`
- disable the append: `[ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true)]`

There are other options too, but those are the ones I'd lean towards.

You remark that the array initialisation is different in the real code, but: I can't comment on code I can't see.

Comment: The init is pretty similar, I meant the usage of this class by other classes is such that I can't change the ctor/init routines too much (at least not without significant refactoring). Thx for the response, I'll check it out soon.

Comment: @Sid and neither of the things shown involve changing the ctor/init routines

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and my `Bytestring` data was actually an XML data I get from the server, so in my application I was already having an XML `Serialaizer`, thus I decided to use that instead of introducing a new `serializer` for `Photobuf` and decorate all of my models, I found this task is very time consuming.

Here is my function which will `deserialize` my `Bytestring`.

```
public SceneDTO ParseSceneAsyncFromByteString(ByteString byteStringData) {
    var serializer = new CustomXmlSerializer(typeof(SceneDTO), _timingManager);
    serializer.UnknownNode += OnUnknownNode;
    serializer.UnknownAttribute += OnUnknownAttribute;

    var ms = new MemoryStream(byteStringData.ToByteArray());
    var scene = (SceneDTO) serializer.Deserialize(ms);

    serializer.UnknownNode -= OnUnknownNode;
    serializer.UnknownAttribute -= OnUnknownAttribute;
    return scene;
}
```

The other reason why I was following this is I was getting the below error after used the `Photobuf` `serializer`.

> Unexpected end-group in source data; this usually means the source
>   data is corrupt photobuf deserialzer

And even after fixing this, my model data was always null, and I decided not to spend many hours in fixing that issue as I already had a working solution.